# Concentric colours on D3 Sunburst diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a Sunburst diagram which uses essentially the same code as the standard at http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426 .

However, I have many many 'nodes' in my final two rings and any combination of colours makes it look extremely messy. As each node within the diagram is pulled from a database I'm unable to assign specific colours to values as the values are all unique.

Is there a way that I could specify a colour for the entirety of each individual ring in the diagram? As an example, I would like it to look somewhat like this:

http://www.design-by-izo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Krakow-3.jpg

That way I would be able to come up with a palette that doesn't clash as much as applying range of colours that d3 just cycles through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you can simply change the `fill` style in the diagram, using `depth` of the respective data, like so:

```
.style('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.depth);
})
```

where `color` is some sort of a color array.

Alternatively, ES6/2015, just:

```
.style('fill', d => color(d.depth))
```

Here's a fiddle, showing you the effect: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chroth/L70hsj2n/)
(based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423))

I hope this is what you want.